# PHP - DOMXpath - Get the value

Tags: php, dom

Here's my code:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($source);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $result = $xpath->evaluate($xpath);
foreach($result as $node) {
     echo $node->nodeValue;

    }


//I'm trying to get the href attribute in: <a href="http://example.com/login">Log In</a>
```

When I evaluate it, I only get Log In.

I want to get the `http://example.com/login`

When I use Python's lxml and evaluate that expression, it works fine.

Comment: Did you try `$node->getAttribute('href');`?

Comment: If `->nodeValue` gives you "Log In", then `->getAttribute('href')` surely would give you the above URL.

Comment: For some reason it printed now. Thank you. You can post so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($result as $node) 
{
 echo $node->getAttribute('href');
}
```

The `nodeValue` property is used to get the text value of a node.

The `getAttribute()` method returns the value of an attribute.